# Prove that the quotient of a topological space $X$ over a relation $R$ over that space is separated.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $R$ an equivalence relation on $X$. Show that, if $R$ is a closed set in $X \times X$ and the function of passage to the quotient is open (i.e. it sends open sets to open sets), then $^{X}/_{R}$ is seperated.

So far I have this:

Let be $\overline{x}, \overline{y} \in \, ^{X}/_{R}$, with $\overline{x} \neq \overline{y}$. Then we have that $(x,y) \in R^{c}$, which is an open set.

Now I don't see how I should apply the fact that the passage function to the quotient is open, since, as far as I know, that function goes from $X \to \, ^{X}/_{R}$, therefore I can't find any open set to send to the quotient space. I can't imagine what a function $X \times X \to \, ^{X}/_{R}$ would do either. How would such a function send a set in $X \times X$ to $^{X}/_{R}$? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: (From context I’m guessing that by *separated* you mean *Hausdorff*: distinct points have disjoint open nbhds.) Use the definition of the product topology on $X\times X$. Since $(X\times X)\setminus R$ is open, there are open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in U\times V\subseteq(X\times X)\setminus R$. Now consider the sets $q[U]$ and $q[V]$, where $q:X\to X/R:x\mapsto\overline x$ is the quotient map.

Comment: So, since any element of the form $(z,z) \in R$, we have that $U,V$ are disjoint (as $U \times V \subset R^c)$. Now $q(U),q(V)$ are open and we need to check that they are disjoint. Assume there is a $\overline{z} \in q(U) \cap q(V)$. Then there are two different $z_1 \in U, z_2 \in V$ with $z_1,z_2 \in \overline{z}$. But then $(z_1,z_2) \in R$ and therefore can't be in $U$ or $V$. Hence such a $\overline{z}$ doesn't exist and $q(U) \cap q(V) = \emptyset$. Is that right?

Comment: @J.C.: Yes, that’s exactly right.